# Twitter bootstrap and carousel touch

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have seen ltos of solution how to make carousel in bootstrap touhch/swipe. But any solutions i used is not working for me. Slider is still dead and works only on arrows. 
Solution with use of jquery mobile:

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#carousel-example-generic").swiperight(function() {
  $(this).carousel('prev');
});
$("#carousel-example-generic").swipeleft(function() {
  $(this).carousel('next');
});
});  
</script>
```

my carousel is

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
http://lazcreative.com/blog/how-to/how-to-adding-swipe-support-to-bootstraps-carousel/

```
<script src=”jquery.mobile.custom.min.js”></script> 

<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
      $("#myCarousel").carousel('prev');  
    });  
   $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
      $("#myCarousel").carousel('next');  
   });  
});  
</script>
```